# What do you call a person who suggested something? A suggester?

Tags: word-request

Let me give an example for context:

If someone posted a question here on the site and I wanted to describe them, I can say "the asker" or "the poster".

Now, if someone suggests an edit on that post, how would I describe them in a similar manner (using a single word)?

Is the word "suggester" correct? (I couldn't find any usage of it.) If it's not, I'm looking for a word that has this meaning. It doesn't have to be derived from "suggest". A synonym would suffice as long as it fits in the context (e.g., "advisor", etc. wouldn't work).

---

#### Update:

<sup>(extra info; feel free to ignore)</sup>

This post appears to have attracted a lot of people so let me try to clarify more.

The example that I used above is very similar to the real-life situation but let me include the exact context that I wanted to use it in anyway. I was trying to come up with a meaningful variable name to use in a software development project that I'm working on. The situation is as follows:

A client suggests something (actually, an edit to an existing item or a proposal for a new item) and I need to have two variables to refer to the following:

- The client that suggested the thing.
- The id of the client who suggested the thing.

I couldn't just use `Client` and `ClientId` because it would be ambiguous in this particular situation. I ended up using `SuggestedBy` and `SuggestedByClientId`. Although the second one isn't perfect (I think), I believe it reflects the intention pretty well. I might change it later to `Proposer` and `ProposerClientId`as suggested by Jason in the answer below or just keep the word "proposer" in mind for future use cases.

Comment: I don't think there's a commonly accepted term for this. My suggestion would be to use their handle. You could also call them a commenter.

Comment: @Katy Actually, that was just an example. It's not the real-life situation; just a very similar context. Thanks for the suggestion though (no pun intended). I accepted the fact that there isn't a single word for this so I guess I'll have to come up with an alternative way.

Comment: @ICloneable Same solution though. Use their name.

Comment: This is context-specific. I would use *editor* in this particular case, but obviously that doesn't apply to other kinds of suggestions.

Comment: Variable names are not really about English, Questions about computing are not a good fit for a stackexchagne about Learning English.

Comment: @JamesK That's **exactly** why I didn't begin my question by making it about the variable. Please feel free to ignore the "Update" section of the post and focus solely on the first part which provides all the information with a context that's almost identical to the real-life situation. Please don't jump to conclusions very quickly. My question _is_ about an English word, and not about variable naming best practices :)

Comment: **"Now, if someone suggests an *edit* on that post"** = the post editor or editor of the post. If you edit something, you are its editor. [correction: edit **to** that post]

Comment: And your question is inaccurate: someone who suggests **an edit**. They didn't suggest going out to dinner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have updated my answer based on several comments I've received.

---

Although it seems that the word *suggester* does actually exist as a variant of [*suggest*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggest) (per Merriam-Webster), I find it so uncommon that, while understandable, it would give most people some pause on reading it.

I would say that a more common word is [**proposer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propose).

> [Merriam-Webster, *propose*]
>   1 : to form or put forward a plan or intention
>   // man *proposes*, but God disposes
>
> Other Words from **propose**
>   **proposer** *noun*

In the right context, such as fields to be filled in on a form, the word would be quite appropriate:

> Proposal: (____)
>
> Proposer: (____)
>
> Approved: (Yes / No)

Also, I've been informed that *proposer* is frequently used in formal debates.

---

As for comparing *suggester* to *proposer*, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suggester%2C%20proposer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuggester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproposer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csuggester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproposer%3B%2Cc0) indicates that *proposer* is far more common, at least in print:

[image: suggester versus proposer]

As I final note, I will add that while *proposer* might sound strange to some, so too would *asker* and *poster*, as used in the question. Just as it would be more common to say *the person who asked* or *the person who posted*, it would also be more common to say *the person who proposed* (or *the person who suggested*). None of these single nouns are as common as a longer phrase; however, *proposer* is still relatively much more common than *suggester*.

Comment: It's used quite a bit in debates, where you have a "proposal" and "proposers". As well as all sorts of rarely used expressions.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! "Proposer" indeed seems to fit in the context. That being said, I just noticed that the same dictionary that you used also mentions "suggester" in the same way: [Other Words from **suggest** --> **suggester** _noun_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggest). Is there a reason one is correct and the other isn't? Or is it just the fact that one is used somewhat frequently and the other isn't?

Comment: @ICloneable Thank you for the comment! While I had looked for *suggester* at Merriam-Webster, I had somehow not found it. (I can only think that I might have accidentally searched for *suggestor* by mistake.) In any case, I have updated my answer to make it more accurate, based on all the feedback I've been given.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any one English word that means "the person who made the suggestion". You have to use several words or a phrase. Like, "the person who made the suggestion".

Based on general patterns of building English words, one might think that "suggester" would be appropriate. But that's just not a word in common use. If you used it, I suppose people would easily guess what you mean, but it would definitely sound odd. If you were writing a long discussion about people who make suggestions, to avoid having to repeat a long phrase over and over you could say, "In this paper I will refer to people who make suggestions as 'suggesters'", and most readers would probably accept that. But I wouldn't use it with no explanation.

Comment: (Or in a formal context at all.)

Answer (score 4):

A single, correct, commonly used and unambiguous word exists, and that word (as Jason Bassford states) is "proposer". Jason's answer does not need to be hedged around with the caveats that it is; when something has been put forward, suggested, floated, hypothesised, ventured, then if you refer to "the proposer" the average English speaker will easily understand you to mean the person who has made the suggestion. No-one will suddenly think someone is about to get married.

This would have been a comment but I'm not able to comment.

Comment: I actually put in the caveats because the use of the word doesn't sound completely natural to me outside of certain contexts. Establishing those contexts might be simple, but they still need to be established. I also think that, more often than not in regular conversation, you would say *who suggested this* or *who proposed this* instead, because *who is the proposer* sounds awkward to me. Then again, *who is the asker* and *who is the poster* sound equally awkward—and the question was really just asking for an equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

A *proposal* is an act of submitting a structured plan of action for approval.  Someone who proposes something is typically waiting for a yes/no response from an approver.

This is not quite synonymous with *suggest*, which means to offer an idea but not stick around to wait for approval.  Hence why companies put out *suggestion boxes* and not *proposal boxes*.

Because a suggestion process doesn't involve waiting for approval, there's usually no need to link back to whoever is suggesting.

> Now, if someone suggests an edit on that post, how would I describe them in a similar manner (using a single word)?

Can the edit be approved or denied?  Does the person making the edit receive notice of approval or denail?  Then you have a *propose* situation and not a *suggest* situation and should use the term *propose* instead.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation! Yes, it does require an approval (see the edit to the question for the exact context). So, do you agree with Jason that the word "proposer" is the one to use in this situation?

Comment: *Proposer* is the word to use and the process should be renamed from *suggest an edit* to *propose an edit*.

Comment: So, StackExchange's [Suggested Edits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) is a wrong usage?

Comment: I would say inexact, and for a good reason: it makes it sound less like a formal, legal process and more like a community process, which might make people feel less bad about having it rejected.

Answer (score 3):

I would put forward the following [variable name](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl///spss/concepts/varnames.html?#:~:text=A%20Variable%20name%20is%20used,dealing%20with%20data%20in%20SPSS.&text=Variable%20names%20must%20be%20unique,period%20(.)%20is%20allowed.); composed by **Suggestion** and **maker**. A *[maker](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/maker)* is a very common noun, it refers to a person who makes something, and to "[make a suggestion](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-make-a-suggestion)" is an extremely common collocation.

**SuggestionMaker**
**IdSuggestionMaker**

In written English it would probably be “suggestion maker”. Sorry, it's not a single word–although the compound noun ***suggestion-maker*** would be acceptable–its meaning remains very clear nevertheless.

I Googled, and lo and behold the term is used, with and without the hyphen.

- The distinction between *[suggestion-maker](https://books.google.it/books?id=kOduCi83O5QC&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=%22suggestion%20maker%22&source=bl&ots=YDJD8LMieL&sig=ACfU3U1OWNkagMTfaSD-tRygabeGvFOmPQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwiou49IDqAhUswcQBHTaqAIAQ6AEwBHoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22suggestion%20maker%22&f=false)* and suggestion-receiver that is at work in all couples can be extrapolated to the level of the crowd.
- If the *[suggestion-maker](https://support.nationbuilder.com/en/articles/2319746-create-a-suggestion-box-page)* is not logged in to your website, they will see an option to log in. Any content in the suggestion text box will not be saved if the suggestion-maker is not already logged in.
- No, I wasn't aware. I thought that the *[suggestion maker](http://wiki.urbandead.com/index.php/Suggestion:20080104_Quick_Barricade_Destruction_Text_Change)* either didn't get to vote, or his vote was automatically considered a keep.
- Are you a big thinker? A question asker? A *[suggestion maker](https://blackbee.ie/careers/)*? A life-long learner? Do you speak up when you need to and grasp opportunities in both hands?

Answer (score 1):

**First example** no one has said *Editor*

They attempted to edit, that became a suggested edit.

> The editor's work was approved

---

**Second example**
I agree with proposer, just going to add more words into the mix

Second example sounds like you have a "Improvement" object and the person who suggested it was the

> *submitter* who submitted

> *creator* who created

> *author* who wrote

> *contributor* who contributed

> *requestor* who requested

a improvement request/change request

Comment: Yes, editor, very simple. People get their knickers in a twist over the simplest things and go off on all sorts of tangents....

Answer (score 0):

Surprised not to see "proponent" here:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proponent

> One who makes a proposal or proposition.

Comment: Proponent is more commonly a person who supports a proposal